# Return random sub-sub-list and its indexes from list

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list with the following arrangement: `N` number of sub-lists and `N_i` number of sub-sub-lists in each sub-list, where `N_i` is not necessarily equal throughout the sub-lists. Each sub-sub-list contains two elements (this is true for all sub-sub-lists). This is what a short version of such a list would look like with 3 sub-lists and 4, 3, 5 and 1 sub-sub-lists:

```
a = [[[0.3, 1.2], [0.3, 2.3], [0.3, 4.6], [0.3, 3.4]], [[0.6, 4.5], [0.6, 2.5], [0.6, 7.8]], [[0.2, 1.4], [0.2, 6.3], [0.2, 5.2], [0.2, 2.1], [0.2, 3.6]], [[0.4, 1.3]]]
```

I need a way to pick a random sub-sub-list from all those available and store the indexes that point to it.

I could use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) and do:

```
import random.choice as r_c
s_s_list = r_c(r_c(a))
print s_s_list
[0.6, 7.8]
```

This effectively returns a random sub-sub-list from all available, but it has the following issues:

a- it doesn't give me the `i,j` indexes that point to it (in this case: `[1, 2]`) and I can't use `a.index(s_s_list)` directly because it is a *sub-sub-list* and

b- since I need to repeat this process `M` times to obtain `M` random **distinct** sub-sub-lists (and the indexes that point to them) this won't work.

c- as has been pointed out in the comments, this gives a higher probability of being picked to those sub-sub-lists inside sub-lists with fewer elements and I need every sub-sub-list picked with the same probability.

Comment: Why don't you use `random.choice` combined with `enumerate`?

Comment: Do you know the size of each sublist in advance?

Comment: Since we're fixing your problem formulation: Should all sublists have an equal probability of being chosen, or should you first choose equally among lists? e.g., in the second case with `[ range(10, 1000), range(1, 2) ]` you have a 50% chance of choosing `2`.

Comment: Please see my updated question once again, both you and arshajii are correct in pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep track of the indices, you can either (a) randomly choose indices, and use them to retrieve the sub-sublists; or (b) fit the indices into your list using `enumerate`.

Since you want sampling without replacement (i.e., `M` **distinct** sub-sub-lists), use `random.sample` instead of `M` calls to `random.choice`. To choose among sublists with equal probability, you must first "flatten" the list. It's easy to do that at the same time that you add the indices.

Here's how to do it with `enumerate`:

```
a_flat = [(i, j, item) for i, sublst in enumerate(a) for j, item in enumerate(sublst)]
choices = random.sample(a_flat, 3)

for c in choices:
    print c

(2, 3, [0.2, 2.1])
(3, 0, [0.4, 1.3])
(1, 0, [0.6, 4.5])
```

Comment: You raise a very important point which I forgot to mention in my original question: the `M` chosen random sub-sub-lists **must be all different**. Sorry guys, I'll update the question right now.

Comment: Then your example is using the wrong approach, regardless of the indexing issue. Use `random.sample`.

Comment: Now choosing without replacement, and uniform probability on the sub-sublists.

Comment: Both are great answers but I'm picking this one because it also outputs the values of the elements, not only the indexes. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`random.randint()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
i = random.randint(0, len(a) - 1)
j = random.randint(0, len(a[i]) - 1)
```

For example:

```
>>> a = [[[0.3, 1.2], [0.3, 2.3], [0.3, 4.6], [0.3, 3.4]], [[0.6, 4.5], [0.6, 2.5], [0.6, 7.8]], [[0.2, 1.4], [0.2, 6.3], [0.2, 5.2], [0.2, 2.1], [0.2, 3.6]], [[0.4, 1.3]]]
>>> 
>>> import random
>>> i = random.randint(0, len(a) - 1)
>>> j = random.randint(0, len(a[i]) - 1)
>>> 
>>> a[i][j]  # <-- this is the actual random element
[0.2, 2.1]
```

An **important note:** The code above is analogous to your code in how it picks a random element. *However*, not all sub-sub-lists have an equal chance of getting picked through this method. For example, consider:

```
[[l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, ...], [l0]]
```

In this case, each sub-sub list in the first sub-list have a low chance of getting picked since we must first pick the first sub list for `i` and *then* pick the right sub-sub list from it for `j`. By contrast, `l0` has a 50% chance of getting picked, since all we must do is pick the second sub-list for `i`, at which point the only option is to pick `l0` for `j`.

---

Your question edit somewhat changes things, since you really need to pick `M` *unique* sub-sub-lists. Now you can try this, using [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> 
>>> M = 4
>>> 
>>> random.sample([(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))], M)
[(1, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (1, 0)]
```

<sup>In Python 2.x, use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.</sup>

Note that with this approach, each sub-sub list *does* have an equal chance of getting picked.

What we're doing here is essentially creating an "index list" with

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))]
```

which contains indices for each sub-sub list in a flat list:

```
>>> [(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0)]
```

We then sample from this list, obtaining the desired result.

Comment: @JoelCornett Why should it matter? Our `j` index depends on the size of the sublist we chose with our `i` index (i.e. "`len(a[i]) - 1`").

Comment: Oh wow, I definitely didn't read through your code correctly. Touché.

Comment: I'm sorry @arshajii, I forgot to add a very important piece of information to the question which alexis pointed out. I've updated it now, sorry again for the inconvenience.

Comment: Well, that's yet **another** very important point. I clearly didn't think this through enough. I'll update the question once again and once again I'm very sorry for the hastiness in posting a half-assed question.